# Updating ActiveWorkbook.Names("X").RefersTo and Names.Value in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have some code that currently looks through the sheet for any cell that I have filled with a light grey, and then adds the value within that cell to a Names list. The goal being that somewhere else in the workbook I can reference this list as a drop down.

Here's my current code:

```
Sub Add_Food_To_List()
  i = 1
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Range("a1:a60").Select
  x = "{"
  y = ""
  first = True
  For Each Cell In Selection
    If ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = "2" Then
      i = i + 1
      If first = False Then
        x = x & ", " & ActiveCell.Value
        y = y & ", " & ActiveCell.Address
      End If
      If first Then
        x = x & ActiveCell.Value
        y = y & ActiveCell.Address
        first = False
      End If
      ActiveWorkbook.Names("Foods").RefersTo = y
      ActiveWorkbook.Names("Foods").Value = x
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
  Next Cell
  Range("a1").Select
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

For some reason these two lines within the `For Each Cell In Selection`:

```
  ActiveWorkbook.Names("Foods").RefersTo = y
  ActiveWorkbook.Names("Foods").Value = x
```

overwrite each other. Whichever goes last ends up as the value that both RefersTo AND Value are set to in the name.

Bonus: This is my first VBA script. How can I get this script to run on the entire workbook, not just the active sheet? Also, how do I make it run automatically on save, or on workbook update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will serve you better:

1. Create a Worksheet in your Workbook with the name `Reference`.
2. Type `Foods` in cell A1 and put at least one random food in cell A2.
3. Create a defined name of `Foods` with the following formula: `=offset(A2,0,0,counta(A:A)-1,1)` This is a [Dynamic Named Ranges](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830287) that will expand or contract as rows are added or deleted (just be sure there are no blank rows in between data).
4. Place the below code in the `ThisWorkbook` module in the VBE. The below code will run right before the Workbook saves. It will loop through each sheet and add the values of any cells highlighted grey in `Range(A1:A60)` to the rowset in column A of the `Reference` Worksheet directly underneath the existing rowset.

Code for Module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        If ws.Name <> "Reference" Then

            With ws

                Dim rCell As Range
                For Each rCell In .Range("a1:a60")

                    If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = "2" Then

                        Dim wsRef As Worksheet
                        Set wsRef = Sheets("Reference")
                        If wsRef.Range("Foods").Find(rCell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then 
                             wsRef.Range("A" & wsRef.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Value = rCell.Value2
                       End If
                    End If

                Next

            End With

        End If

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```

Comment: I started working in the direction of this solution after I posted the question, but the dynamic range, and this pre-save hook were incredibly helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Just as an update, the post-save hook doesn't check for duplicates before appending the values. I'm looking into fixing this now. Just wanted to give a heads up.

Comment: @MikeM. - That was not listed in the original requirement, but it is in easy enough fix :) See my edited code as one way to approach it.

Comment: I'll be the first to admit I'm not the best when it comes to requirements definition >_< Thanks for all your help! You're right, that was a fairly easy fix (for someone who knows what they're doing haha). Would you mind explaining what `lookat:=xlWhole` is? I've never seen that before.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @MikeM. A lot of sloppiness by me today on SO! Anyway, rather than explain the `lookat` argument, I'll point to the [MSDN Page for Range.Find Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) where you can learn the power of all the arguments!